# Link redirects me to xampp dashboard

Tags: php, html

When I hover over my categories it says the link will redirect me to:

localhost/?page=catalogue&category=3

but when I click it, it redirects me to localhost/dashboard.

Does anyone know why it does this and how to fix this?

Here is my code for _header.php

```
    <?php
    $objCatalogue = new Catalogue();
    $cats = $objCatalogue->getCategories();

    $objBusiness = new Business();
    $business = $objBusiness->getBusiness();
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Ecommerce website project</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Ecommerce website project" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ecommerce website project" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <link href="css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
     <div id="header_in">
       <h5><a href="/"><?php echo $business['name']; ?></a></h5>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div id="outer">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left">
          <h2>Categories</h2>
          <ul id="navigation">
            <?php
                if (!empty($cats)) {
                  foreach($cats as $cat) {
                    echo "<li><a href=\"/?page=catalogue&amp;category=".$cat['id']."\"";
                    echo Helper::getActive(array('category' => $cat['id']));
                    echo ">";
                    echo Helper::encodeHtml($cat['name']);
                    echo "</a></li>";
          }
        }
    ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
```

Comment: Put your application files in a subdirectory inside htdocs to avoid confusion between your application and XAMPP

Comment: Hello Ahmad, thank you for your reply but my application files are already inside a subdirectory in htdocs named Shop so I think that is not the problem.

Comment: So why are you linking to the root of your server?

Comment: Can you be more specific please, I can share my code if that would help?

Comment: This is the target of your link: `localhost/?page=catalogue&category=3`, that points to the root of the server. But you said that your files are in `Shop` subdirectory, so it must be something like this: `localhost/Shop/?page=catalogue&category=3`

Comment: Maybe I can help more if you show me the code

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a page name.

in

> localhost/?page=catalogue&category=3

you have the server:

> localhost

the frontslash indicates a folder inside the server.

> /

The ? mark indicates the $_GET function for PHP. This will only work if there is a page to process it.

> ?page=catalogue&category=3

So you are missing a page like index.php, or businesslist.php
which would look like

> localhost/index.php?page=catalogue&category=3

With that being said, it also looks like you're pulling from the root of the server (XAMPP) with localhost.
XAMPP uses a folder called htdocs to house your web files. So you can  practice building multiple sites at the same time by giving them different folder names and keeping them in that folder. i.e:

```
>htdocs
-->website1
-->website2 etc...
```

in each folder you would have the index and other pages and folders. So if we say your building a website called FredsCajunSpices.com you could use fredscajunspices as the folder name and call it in your webfiles like so.

> localhost/fredscajunspices/index.php?page=catalogue&category=3

When you finish the site and move it to the web, you will need to search and replace all the "localhost/fredscajunspices/" with "", then your link will be relative to the domain. or you could make the full link and search/replace "localhost/fredscajunspices/" with "http://www.fredscajunspices.com/".

Comment: Yes that has helped, but now it's giving me a mysqli error and i cannot figure it out either...

Comment: did you google the error, I've solved almost all my unknown errors with google and stackoverflow . Chances are high if you barely know mysqli or php, someone else has made your mistake.
just a thought, your database server should be on localhost, or you have to call its exact address...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I downloaded a opencart from live and set it on local but when I open a link which does not contain any index.php, for example
https://localhost/opencart/login It takes me to the xampp dashboard so I have changed the .htaccess file.
Add the below code in your .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.twig|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied

</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /tsmpk_test/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/storage/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**NOTE** If your opencart is not in main web folder make sure to enter the name of your folder in RewriteBase where I write it as '/tsmpk_test/' If it is in main folder make sure you only write '/' .